# refresh list/grid view on ajax

Tags: yii, yii2

These used to work on yii 1 for reloading a list view / grid view externally. How can we do the same with yii 2 ?

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update

$.fn.yiiGridView.update
```

It gives above are undefined error though AppAsset has depends  on 'yii\web\YiiAsset'

**EDIT**

It seems there is still an asset file for GridView, but I am not finding any such asset for ListView

```
'yii\grid\GridViewAsset'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#grid-id").yiiGridView("applyFilter");` or if you use pjax, you can use `$.pjax.reload({container: "#pjax-id"});`

Comment: Is there similar yiiListView as well ?

Comment: No, to ListView you can only use pjax reload

Comment: $.pjax.reload sends request to current URL which can be different from URL that gives List view dataprovider. I think we will need to remove Pjax::begin from PHP in that case and call directly from js as $.pjax{url:.. } for that ? Also since it will redirect in case pjax is disabled / timesout,  that action I believe should check X-PJAX header and renderAjax / Redirect accordingly.Can you please update your example with above scenario where URL is different from listview provider than current url ?